# FrameLayout IOS alternative

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

Is there a layout in which items can be put one on top of another in layers like in Android's FrameLayout?

I have been googling for some time and couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: Look at using a `UIStackView`

Comment: @Nathan no, UIStackView is like Android's LinearLayout. It is hard to describe... I would like to put one element on another like layers in photoshop...

Comment: Are you looking just to `addSubview` or `addSublayer`, or are you looking for a framework to make that process easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this answer is clear and could help you.
What you need is **addSubview()**. Here is example how to implement it:

```
    let viewA = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
    viewA.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(viewA)

    let viewB = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    viewB.backgroundColor = .blue
    viewA.addSubview(viewB)

    let viewC = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    viewC.backgroundColor = .green
    viewB.addSubview(viewC)
```

The result of the code above:

[image]

Cheers :)

Comment: Looks like that's it. Thanks :)